# React native firebase push notification not working for iOS

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have recently upgraded my RN 0.57.1 to RN 0.59.1, Push notification is working properly earlier but now push notification only working when the app installed first time.

**package.json:**

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.59.1",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0"
```

I have tried with https://pushtry.com to test the actual issue and it's showing me "**NotRegistered**". It was working perfect in my old builds but I don't know why it's creating issues.

Here is my code:

**info.plist:**

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>no</string>
<key>FirebaseDataCollectionDefaultEnabled</key>
<string>Yes</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
```

**app.js:**

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.checkPermission();
  this.createNotificationListeners();
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.notificationListener();
  this.notificationOpenedListener();
}
async createNotificationListeners() {
  this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
         const { title, body} = notification.data;
         this.title = title;
         this.body = body;

         const localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
           sound: 'default',
           show_in_foreground: true,
         })
         .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
         .setTitle(notification.title)
         .setBody(notification.body)
         .setData(notification.data)
         .android.setAutoCancel(true)
         .android.setChannelId('mybeautysquad') // e.g. the id you chose above
         .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher') // create this icon in Android Studio
         .android.setColor('#000000') // you can set a color here
         .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);

         firebase.notifications()
         .displayNotification(localNotification)
         .catch(err => console.error(err));
     });

     /*
     * If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
     * */
     this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
         const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification.data;
         this.title = title;
         this.body = body;
     });

     /*
     * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
     * */
     const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
     if (notificationOpen) {
         const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification.data;
         this.title = title;
         this.body = body;

     }
     /*
     * Triggered for data only payload in foreground
     * */
     this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
       //process data message
       console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
     });
}
 async checkPermission() {
     const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
     if (enabled) {
         this.getToken();
     } else {
         this.requestPermission();
     }
   }

   async getToken() {
     let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
     console.log(fcmToken);
     if (!fcmToken) {
         fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
         if (fcmToken) {
             // user has a device token
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('fcmToken', fcmToken);
         }
     }
   }

   async requestPermission() {
     try {
         await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
         // User has authorised
         this.getToken();
     } catch (error) {
         // User has rejected permissions
         console.log('permission rejected');
     }
   }
```

Also, I am saving sane FCM token on the server when login and check if user FCM token not updated in login then I am also updating their FCM device token when they update their profile.

Please let me know if anyone can help me into this...Thanks!

Comment: whether the registration token is updated in the table ?? if you uninstall the app and install it again the registration token will change

Comment: Yes when i login it will change the token but nothing helped.

Comment: I tried here https://pushtry.com and it is showing notregistered.

Comment: token is auto generated.You cannot generate.Also in IOS the token is changes only when app is uninstalled and installed again.

Comment: I mean getToken

Comment: Did you add openUrl: method in your iOS native ? I have a working project with FCM and RN 0.61

Comment: No, I didn't, if you have a working project, please share the answer here so I can check if I am missing something.